# Application is crashing from concurrent access to variables

Tags: ios

I have been trying to debug this problem for a while, and I am not sure what I can do. I am not very good at what I am doing, so please stop me at any logical fallacy.

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 error. It happens sporadically. Whenever it crashes, the symbol window shows that everything being accessed is not nil, so I am assuming that means when the thread goes into assembly, the data is modified by another thread and causes the crash.

**I start a serial dispatch queue for my video output**, so that the interface runs smoother (otherwise, my game is choppy)

```
- (void) addVideoDataOutput {
    // (1) Instantiate a new video data output object
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput * captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;

    // (2) The sample buffer delegate requires a serial dispatch queue
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.tangible.videooutput", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    // (3) Define the pixel format for the video data output
    NSString * key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey;
    NSNumber * value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];
    NSDictionary * settings = @{key:value};
    [captureOutput setVideoSettings:settings];

    // (4) Configure the output port on the captureSession property
    [self.captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];
}
```

This thread starts and runs every time data from the camera is ready. This causes potentially concurrent reads and writes to variables accessed in "com.example.tangible.videooutput". I am using DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, so that means everything runs one at a time in the queue. Does that mean a different thread outside of the queue is editing these variables? (I don't think that happens in my code)

Based on my assumption that multiple threads are accessing some variables at the same time (which shouldn't be happening because I am using a serial dispatch queue), I have changed the variables that are accessed by the thread to atomic and copy. This did not stop the crashes.

I am at a stage where I feel like I need to make a deep copy (these are linked lists that are being accessed concurrently) of each list before I call any operation on them, and I feel like this is wasteful and unnecessary.

I do not understand why these variables are being accessed concurrently, as I am using a serial dispatch queue, and I do not believe that anything outside of threads in that queue is accesses these linked lists.

Here is a picture of where it crashes (sometimes), and the variable.
[image]

Here is a backtrace:

```
* thread #6: tid = 0x8ed94, 0x0000000191b641dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 28, queue = 'com.example.tangible.videooutput'
    frame #0: 0x0000000191b641dc libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 28
  * frame #1: 0x00000001000f5508 Tangible`-[ControlScene removeBlocks](self=0x000000015450cc60, _cmd=0x0000000100556388) + 2096 at ControlScene.mm:342
    frame #2: 0x00000001000f5764 Tangible`-[ControlScene updateBlocks:](self=0x000000015450cc60, _cmd=0x00000001005559fe, b=0x000000017045a580) + 276 at ControlScene.mm:362
    frame #3: 0x00000001000e7e08 Tangible`-[StageViewController frameReady:](self=0x0000000154612f70, _cmd=0x0000000100555a0c, frame=<unavailable>) + 640 at StageViewController.mm:94
    frame #4: 0x00000001000ebbb0 Tangible`-[VideoSource captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:](self=0x0000000170261e80, _cmd=0x0000000183fe21c9, captureOutput=0x0000000170223840, sampleBuffer=0x00000001586091e0, connection=0x0000000170610080) + 340 at VideoSource.mm:131
    frame #5: 0x0000000183f683c4 AVFoundation`__74-[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput _AVCaptureVideoDataOutput_VideoDataBecameReady]_block_invoke + 412
    frame #6: 0x000000019212c014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    frame #7: 0x000000019212bfd4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #8: 0x00000001921324a8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 640
    frame #9: 0x000000019212e4c0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 68
    frame #10: 0x00000001921330f4 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 104
    frame #11: 0x00000001921334fc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76
    frame #12: 0x00000001922c16bc libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 356
```

Please advice. I don't understand what is going on and I have had this bug for quite some time. I will gladly provide any other snippets of code upon request.

Comment: Can you share more info re the crash? (Which thread? Always same place? Please share full stack trace.) Can you share more info re what video processing thread is doing and what main thread (or any other thread) is doing with the same model? The suggestion of using `atomic` and `copy` to achieve thread safety is a little worrisome (generally you'd use some form of lock or synchronization queue for the mutating structure), but I hesitate to jump to that conclusion without more info.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by full stack trace. Does this suffice? http://i.imgur.com/6SLtBVw.png

Comment: I don't think any thread other than the video processing thread is doing anything to the same model. As you can see in the stack traces, Thread 3 is the only thing that contains code written by me. Or am I reading the stack trace incorrectly?

Comment: The video processing thread also updates two SKScenes. Should I put that back into the main thread?

Comment: Yes, I'd try dispatching the SKScene updates back to the main thread. I was assuming from your other conversation about synchronizing with `atomic`/`copy` that the main thread was trying to access the model that this video processing thread was updating. I gather that's not the case.

Comment: I have dispatched updates to SKScene to the main thread. Currently, the scene that is updating is reading its instance variables retrieved from the video processing thread. These instance variables are deep copies, using StringWithString for NSString and NSKeyedUnarchiver for the NSArray.

Comment: The video processing thread updates the SKScene every time it is finished processing, and I have dispatched that to the main thread, using dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{. I am very confused as to why there are even concurrent accesses to any variables.

Comment: Here is another image of a more recent crash, after all the updates. http://i.imgur.com/ArIG6GQ.png I'm not sure if it's worth noting, but here the video processing thread is thread 6, but this thread number changes from 4, to 6, to 7. Is this relevant?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a new dispatch queue each time the function is called:
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.tangible.videooutput", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

So they might not be able to synchronize. Have you tried to create the queue only once?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For requesting clarifications and more information please use comments.

Comment: I just tried making the queue an instance variable and then running it--same thing happened. Bad pointer access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not concurrent access, so making variables atomic or putting locks on them was not helping the situation.

I had linked lists inside mutable arrays, but these mutable arrays were not declared as strong. Neither were the objects each linked list node was pointing to. So, by changing those properties to strong, all the crashes went away =)